# Panelizer content missing on module update

Tags: blocks, panels

I'm in the process of migrating a client's Drupal 8 installation to the preferred composer structure (outside of docroot), but having a single issue causing a full stop. They use Panelizer for most pages, and most layouts are Flexible (flexible_layout). The issue is that anything that uses the Flexible layout seems unable to see any blocks. Other layouts are fine. The Flexible layout itself seems intact, all rows/regions are where they should be and labeled properly, just missing the blocks. The blocks are still there, as reverting the change fixes the problem.

Current (working) setup.

- Drupal 8.9.7
- Panelizer 8.x-4.1
- Panels 8.x-4.3
- Ctools 8.x-3.0
- Composer inside docroot, but not for modules, only core.

Steps I've tried:

- Migrate composer to outside docroot, use composer for all modules,
  pinned at current versions.
- Migrate composer as above, also update Drupal to 8.9.11 (before 12
  came out).
- Migrate composer as above, let all modules update as needed, also update Drupal to 8.9.11 (before 12 came out).
- Only update panelizer/panels/ctools. Tried going up one release each,
  and going fully current.

Every step always ends up with the empty Content page for a Flexible layout. Everything else all seems to work fine. Reverting any step gets it working fine again.
When the Content page is empty, the front end of the node is blank except for anything not part of the panelized page (header/footer/template renderings/etc).
I *think* this is specifically in panelizer, but can't be sure. It also happens when just doing the composer migration and keeping the versions the same...

Question: Does anybody know what could cause the disappearing blocks?

I have no contact with the original developers, and am not very familiar with the inner workings of Drupal.

Comment: "Every step always ends up with the empty Content page for a Flexible layout." Are there any errors in the log (`/admin/reports/dblog`)?

Comment: Nothing that isn't present before and after, and they don't seem related to this. I will work on clearing them up anyway just in case.

Comment: Assuming you have already exported config with drush and you're using version control, I would next try exporting the config immediately after migrating composer while keeping the modules at the same versions.  Then git diff the config to see if somehow the modules are not being migrated properly.

Comment: Enabling dblog made me look at other module issues that were happening, and I think I might have finally solved this. After fixing other module issues before updating ctools/panels/panelizer, things seem to be working correctly. Still a bit boggling, as the other modules have nothing to do with these three. I couldn't take them all the way current yet, that still has the same issue, but I will work on updating everything else as well.